# Как найти индекс нажатого элемента среди элементов блока при делегировании событий

Tags: javascript, события, dom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сверстал такую клавиатуру. У меня висит обработчик события клика на всю клавиатуру, а затем я определяю какая клавиша была нажата с помощью метода .closest(). Вопрос заключается в том как найти индекс этого нажатого элемента, например у клавиши с цифрой 1 индекс должен быть 0. Я пробовал использовать keyboard.children.indexOf(key), но данное выражение всегда возвращало -1. Возможно есть какой-то лучший способ. Пока не скидываю код, жду общих ответов, но если понадобится, то скину.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось (нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow). Можно было написать так: `[...key.parentElement.children].indexOf(key)`. Ну и key.parentElement можно естественно заменить на keyboard (то есть на родителя)